# How can I get my "clickMe!" button to work after I clear? All I get is "time's up!"

Tags: javascript

What I would like to happen after I use my Clear button, is to have my timer restart when I click the Click Me button another time. No matter what I try it will not work.

```js
var sec = 5;
var timerID;

document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
  timerID = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
};

function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
    myTimer()
  }

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sec + "sec.";
  sec--;
  if (sec <= -1) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $("#demo").html("");
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="b1">Click Me!</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button id="b2">Clear!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

What I would like my "Click Me" button to do the second time is to restart the timer. Thatis not what is happening. I ave tried many things all to no avail.

Comment: Why are you mixing plain JavaScript and jQuery like this?

Comment: call clearInterval(timerID); after clearing

Comment: 1. I'm learning and using whatever works. 2. I have no Idea what esQmois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This Out! :)

```js
var sec = 5;
var timerID;

document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
  timerID = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
};

function myTimer() {
//   document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
//     myTimer()
//   }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sec + "sec.";
  sec--;
  if (sec <= -1) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    sec = 5;
    $("#demo").html("");
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="b1">Click Me!</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button id="b2">Clear!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! that got me closer. Now what happens after I clear, is with each click of the "Click Me!" button the counter shows 5secs., then 4secs., then 3secs., then 2 secs., then 1 secs., then "Time's Up!".

Comment: Thank you, it is now working with your changes  and a change made by Barmar(see above) which I missed yesterday. I appreciate your expertise, and your willingness to help a "newbie". Maybe, one day, I will be able to return the favor!!!!

Comment: I'm too new to stack, If you find it useful! Kindly upvote this answer.

Comment: Upvoted!! If you ever have time, can you explain to me why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the element's `innerHTML`, you also need to clear the interval.

```js
var sec = 5;
var timerID;
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
  timerID = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
};

function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
    myTimer()
  }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sec + "sec.";
  sec--;
  if (sec <= -1) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $("#demo").html("");
    clearInterval(timerID);
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="b1">Click Me!</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button id="b2">Clear!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't see any solution changes. I though I had done both things you suggested.

Comment: @astroboyee You weren't clearing the interval inside the `#b2` click event listener. See the third last line.

Answer (score 0):

The `myTimer()` function is removing the `onclick` action that starts the timer.

Just have the Clear button stop the timer, and keep the original `onclick`.

```js
var sec = 5;
var timerID;

document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {
  timerID = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
};

function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sec + "sec.";
  sec--;
  if (sec <= -1) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $("#demo").html("");
    clearInterval(timerID);
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="b1">Click Me!</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button id="b2">Clear!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I admit when I fist looked at your solution yesterday, I missed your "change " to my code.I removed the second b1 click, and it helped. I still needed the additional lines added to my last jquery, provided by Shivam Sharma(see below), and it is now working! Thanks again, and now I'll try to work on using js or jquery only!!!